# How do I type the lü for Character Romanization?

Tags: pinyin, input-methods

I am studying classical Chinese and when I try to type in any words that require the ü it just randomly chooses a character.

How do I use the Traditional pinyin entry method on a Mac and get the the ü?

Thanks.

Comment: Type "v" instead of "u".

Comment: Does the Mac have similar alt+xxx combos as in Windows?

Comment: @deutschZuid He's asking about entering it in a _pinyin IME_. If you actually want to type a `ü` on a mac, you just hold down `u` really long until a menu comes up with various `u`'s with accents.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Ah thanks. I didn't know that (never been much of a Mac user).

Comment: For anone interested, on Windows it's ALT-0252 for ü or ALT-0220 for Ü

Comment: If I hold the U down for a long time I get a lot of UUUUUUs

Comment: @fmz See my very first comment: When using a _pinyin IME for Chinese characters_, type `v` instead of `ü`. Many of the answers people are giving are how to actually type a `ü` (_not_ to type characters)

Comment: Brilliant. Can you elevate your comment to an answer so I can give you credit? Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The OP is asking how to type characters, using a pinyin IME, when those characters have a `ü` in their pinyin spelling. For example, how do you type `绿`=`lü`? This is different than asking how to actually type the letter `ü`. The answer is to type a `v`. To follow the example, change to the pinyin IME, type `lv` and select `绿`.

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to acknowledge this. Typing the 'v' works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Type option-u then u on a Mac.

Comment: This works for English or European language input, but it does not work with the Chinese language input.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant when typing pinyin for itself -- ie not to get Chinese in the end but to show pinyin. My bad.